# Is there a way to check the losslessness of a FLAC file in Linux?

Tags: audio, conversion, mp3, flac

Let me explain my question with greater detail: I know `FLAC` is a lossless audio format **with respect to the original file;** this is, any piece of audio encoded with `FLAC` will be preserved completely. But say I got an CD album in `MP3` format (which is, of course, lossy) and then decide to re-encode it in `FLAC` and give this "lossless" version to a friend. How does he/she know that the file received from me is not an exact copy of the CD album but a camouflaged lossy copy? I've read something about it and it seems there is some app for Windows which identifies this fake `FLACs` but I haven't found anything like that for Linux. So my question is: Is there a way to tell real `FLACs` from fake ones in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

You want a spectrogram program like spek.
http://spek.cc/
If it is mp3 to flac you will see a cutoff around 16-18kHz where the spectrogram gets blocky.

Comment: Can you please expand this answer a bit? Link only answers are discouraged on SE sites.